# Numerical integral of finite valued function over finite integral fails with NIntegrate::inumri

Tags: numerical-integration, special-functions

I have the following (simplified) integral:

```
f[x_, x0_] := Sinh[x]/(Cosh[2 x] + Cosh[2 x0])
g[x_, xp_] := EllipticK[(4 x xp)/(x + xp)^2]/(x + xp)
NIntegrate[
 f[x, 101.] f[xp, 101.] g[x, xp], {x, 51., 101.}, {xp, 50., x-10.^-6}, 
 PrecisionGoal -> 6, MaxRecursion -> 100]
```

For me (with Mathematica v. 10.3), the integral fails with

`NIntegrate::inumri: "The integrand (...) has evaluated to Overflow, Indeterminate, or Infinity for all sampling points the region with boundaries {{0.,9.35762*10^-14},{0,1}}"`

Why is that? Both `f` and `g` are finite and well defined for all values (in particular in the integration range).

Also, the "boundaries" given in the error message do not make sense to me. How do I read this? None of these values are in the interval `[51, 101]`.

When I omit the `MaxRecursion` parameter, the integral gives a warning instead of an error saying that it could not get a correct value with the given number of recursions (wrong number and no number seem equally bad to me).

Edit:

It also fails when defining `f` and `g` to be numeric:

```
f[x_?NumericQ, x0_?NumericQ] := Sinh[x]/(Cosh[2 x] + Cosh[2 x0])
g[x_?NumericQ, xp_?NumericQ] := 
 EllipticK[(4 x xp)/(x + xp)^2]/(x + xp)
NIntegrate[
 f[x, 101.] f[xp, 101.] g[x, xp], {x, 51., 101.}, {xp, 50., 
  x - 10.^-6}, 
 Method -> {"GlobalAdaptive", "MaxErrorIncreases" -> 100000}, 
 MaxRecursion -> 100]
```

The `MaxErrorIncreases` parameter was required to avoid warnings about inaccurate results.

In my real application, `f` has an additional factor `Cosh[x0]` that I omitted here because it is a constant factor in the integral. Just now, it happens that `f` evaluates to very small numbers, but again, this should only be a constant factor. The same result is obtained with `WorkingPrecision -> 20`.

**Edit2:**

Since there was some concern about the small values of the function `f`, here another function that gives the same problem:

```
f2[x_?NumericQ, x0_?NumericQ] := Sech[x - x0] (1 - x Tanh[x - x0])
NIntegrate[
 f2[x, 100.] f2[xp, 100.] g[x, xp], {x, 51., 101.}, {xp, 50., 
  x - 10.^-6}, 
 Method -> {"GlobalAdaptive", "MaxErrorIncreases" -> 100000}, 
 MaxRecursion -> 100]
```

With the previous value of `x0=101`, this new integral gives a value without any error messages, but with `x0=100`, it fails as before. It seems to be quite random when the integral can be calculated and when not.

Comment: Note that `g[51, 51]`, which happens to be on one of the boundaries of your region of integration, evaluates to `ComplexInfinity`, so perhaps your functions are not as finite-valued as you thought.

Comment: That's true, well spotted. However, I get the same error when excluding the point `x=xp` from the integration (i.e., by stopping at `xp=x-1e-6`, see edits to the question.

Comment: You may want to prevent symbolic evaluation of `f` and `g` using `NumericQ`; that's typically safer for numerical evaluations: `f[x_?NumericQ, x0_?NumericQ] := ...` and similarly with `g`. See http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/26037/27951. I'm not sure that this will fix the problem though. The `f` and `g` functions evaluate to very very small numbers over your domain. Instead of a `PrecisionGoal`, try using only exact numbers in your definitions, and setting `WorkingPrecision -> $MachinePrecision` (or higher) to enable arbitrary-precision arithmetic and error tracking.

Comment: Thanks for this tip, but unfortunately, the problem persists (see edit).

Comment: Have you tried plotting your integrand with `Plot3D[]`, just to check that what you're integrating is not nasty-looking?

Comment: 2D plots of `f` and 3D plots of `g` look good. For some reason, it can plot the product `f[x, 101.] f[xp, 101.] g[x, xp]` only after multiplying with `Cosh[202]`, but then the result looks fine everywhere. In the integral, the `Cosh[202]` factor has no effect.

Comment: @Felix consider that `Cosh[202]` is a *very large* number; the rest of your original integrand is a *very small* number, so perhaps the product comes out reasonable-valued. Notice also that, as long as you have machine-precision numbers in your integrand (such as `101.`), the `WorkingPrecision` setting won't have any effect. In fact, you should receive a warning when you try to increase working precision past machine precision, indicating that your integrand has insufficient precision.

Comment: @Marco: True, for the working precision test I replaced the floating point numbers by integers. Regarding the small number issue, to my understanding, numbers down to about $10^{-300}$ can be represented with 64 bit machine precision. Just differences between very small and very large numbers would be problematic, but I don't see where these occur in the present example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us have a single integrand function first:

```
F[x_?NumericQ, xp_?NumericQ] := (
  EllipticK[(4 x xp)/(x + xp)^2] Sinh[x] Sinh[
    xp])/((x + xp) (Cosh[202] + Cosh[2 x]) (Cosh[202] + Cosh[2 xp]));
```

obtained by expanding `f[x, 101.] f[xp, 101.] g[x, xp]`.

> For me (with Mathematica v. 10.3), the integral fails with
>
> NIntegrate::inumri: "The integrand (...) has evaluated to Overflow,
>   Indeterminate, or Infinity for all sampling points the region with
>   boundaries {{0.,9.35762*10^-14},{0,1}}"
>
> Why is that? Both f and g are finite and well defined for all values
>   (in particular in the integration range).

This is because of the singularity handler ["DuffyCoordinates"](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NIntegrateIntegrationStrategies.html#738848244). With no singularity handler or ["IMT"](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NIntegrateIntegrationStrategies.html#159907828) the integration process finishes only issuing "NIntegrate::slwcon".

```
NIntegrate[F[x, xp], {x, 51., 101.}, {xp, 50., x - 10.^-6}, 
 Method -> {"GlobalAdaptive", "SingularityHandler" -> None}, 
 PrecisionGoal -> 6, MaxRecursion -> 100]

(* 2.06466*10^-90 *)
```

If larger precision is used again only the message "NIntegrate::slwcon" is issued:

```
NIntegrate[F[x, xp], {x, 51, 101}, {xp, 50, x - 10^-6}, 
 WorkingPrecision -> 60, PrecisionGoal -> 6, MaxRecursion -> 100]

(*2.06466493230756122140054681757475975443145922411426227150693*10^-90 *)
```

### Sampling points

Compare the following plots of integration sampling points. The first is with the automatic singularity handling, the second with IMT, the third without any:

```
Needs["Integration`NIntegrateUtilities`"]

Grid[{
  Table[
   (k = 0;
    NIntegrate[F[x, xp], {x, 51., 101.}, {xp, 50., x - 10.^-6}, 
     Method -> {"GlobalAdaptive", "SingularityHandler" -> sh}, 
     EvaluationMonitor :> (k++), PrecisionGoal -> 6, 
     MaxRecursion -> 100];
    gr = NIntegrateSamplingPoints[
      NIntegrate[F[x, xp], {x, 51., 101.}, {xp, 50., x - 10.^-6}, 
       Method -> {"GlobalAdaptive", "SingularityHandler" -> sh}, 
       PrecisionGoal -> 6, MaxRecursion -> 100]]; 
    Append[Append[gr, ImageSize -> Medium], 
     PlotLabel -> 
      Row[{"SingularityHandler: ", sh, 
        "\nnumber of sampling points: ", k}]]), {sh, {Automatic, 
     "IMT", None}}]}, Dividers -> All]
```

[image]

It seems that using IMT produces (seemingly) less points.

With larger working precision (60) much less sampling points are needed:

[image]

This can be explained with integrand's structure. Additionally, with "DuffyCoordinates" the integrand gets more complicated.

Comment: That makes sense. Now it is also clear why the error message complains about a parameter range that is not within the integration range: Because of the transformation of variables by the singularity handler.

Comment: Correct, I thought but forgot to mention that...

Comment: How peculiar. Duffy is supposed to be the "cheaper" substitution, since it does not involve a transformation with transcendental equations unlike IMT. Also, with IMT, you are then forced to do a Cartesian product integration, which makes it unsuitable for Genz-Malik. But I guess the cost of evaluating the integrand itself trumps everything else.

Comment: @J.M. This kind of seems to be the case -- see the updated plots in my answer.